# Convert MP4 to OGG (Video)

Tags: video, conversion, mp4, ogg

Does anyone know a way to convert .mp4 video to `.ogg` video (in Windows)? None of the converters I've seen online seem to do the job.

Comment: For people looking to convert `.mp4` video to `.ogg` audio on Linux, it's `avconv -i input.mp4 -nv output.ogg`.

Comment: this works: http://www.online-convert.com/

Comment: @minitech: On Ubuntu 14.04 it says `Unrecognized option 'nv'`

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Sorry, it’s `-vn`, rather.

Answer (score 21):

I see people promoting SUPER quite often and I'm not sure why, when options such as Miro or plain old FFmpeg are available?

To do this with ffmpeg just use this (simple) command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec:v libtheora -qscale:v 3 -codec:a libvorbis \
  -qscale:a 3 -f ogv output.ogv
```

`-qscale` is required to keep a reasonable video and audio quality, otherwise the default is very bad, see also: [How do I convert MP4 to OGV while still retaining the same quality using FFMPEG?](https://superuser.com/questions/1096841/how-do-i-convert-mp4-to-ogv-while-still-retaining-the-same-quality-using-ffmpeg/1096865)

Tested in Ubuntu 19.04, ffmpeg 4.3.1.

Miro: http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/

Comment: audio/video quality level should be specified with `-qscale:v` and `-qscale:a` - see  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide  -- default is very low quality

Comment: There is a typo. Should be ogg not ogv. I cant edit as it requires 6+ characters so I commented instead.

Comment: The format was ogg video or ogv at the time of posting 7 years ago now; if it has changed then sure, but I doubt its relevant.

Comment: @Paolo thanks for this, I've edited them into the answer. ogv seems to be the preferred format btw: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day. I think this demonstrate that 4k and 8k are only hype :D

Answer (score 3):

[SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) is a gui frontend for ffmpeg, so it can convert mp4 into ogg.

Answer (score 1):

[Format Factory](https://format-factory.en.softonic.com//) is the best for all...

- Format Factory is a multifunctional media converter. Provides
  functions below: All to MP4/3GP/MPG/AVI/WMV/FLV/SWF. All to
  MP3/WMA/AMR/OGG/AAC/WAV. All to JPG/BMP/PNG/TIF/ICO/GIF/TGA. Rip DVD
  to video file , Rip Music CD to audio file. MP4 files support
  iPod/iPhone/PSP/BlackBerry format. Supports RMVB,Watermark, AV Mux.
- Format Factory's Feature: 1 support converting all popular
  video,audio,picture formats to others. 2 Repair damaged video and
  audio file. 3 Reducing Multimedia file size. 4 Support iphone,ipod
  multimedia file formats. 5 Picture converting supports
  Zoom,Rotate/Flip,tags. 6 DVD Ripper. 7 Supports 56 languages
- OS requirements: All 32 windows OS

Comment: link is broken, got redirected to a fake site

Comment: corrected link...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good video converter that can convert pretty much anything to anything, I would highly recommend [Handbrake](http://www.handbrake.fr). It is free and open source.

Comment: I personally can't recommend Handbrake on the OS specified in the question. I've tried it and haven't had very good luck.

Comment: @Mondain - Handbrake on Windows is great, it is the only video converter I use now.

Comment: I used Handbrake on windows and never had any luck with it

Comment: Handbrake [removed support](https://handbrake.fr/news.php?article=10) for OGG in 2009, just before this answer was posted.