# Looking for (Free) Conversion Software to Output .OGV/.OGG

Tags: video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert MP4 to OGG (Video)](https://superuser.com/questions/108237/convert-mp4-to-ogg-video)

Does anyone know of any freeware that can take video in most any format and convert it to .OGV? I am trying to play video through my web pages and it seems that Firefox and Opera do not like .MP4 -- they require .OGV

Thank you for your help and direction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert MP4 to OGG (Video)](http://superuser.com/questions/108237/convert-mp4-to-ogg-video) -- although the question is slightly different, the software in the accepted answer handles pretty much any kind of video you can throw at it.

Answer (score 0):

hope this might be helpful for you. [OGV Conversion](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091026005429AAGq8FE)

Comment: you are always welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

mencoder (part of mplayer package) and ffmpeg should do the job