# How do I convert MP4 to OGV while still retaining the same quality using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm not familiar with FFMPEG at all and would like to know how to convert MP4 to OGV format while still keeping the same video and audio quality?

Comment: Related no quality request: https://superuser.com/questions/108237/convert-mp4-to-ogg-video

Comment: Both containers store different codecs. If the codec is *H.264* then OGV cannot store it, you'll loose some quality in re-encoding, the quality may degrade further. **TL;DR** if the video codec isn't supported on both formats you're surely going to loose quality.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Basic command is

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libtheora -q:v 7 -c:a libvorbis -q:a 4 output.ogv
```

You'll have to fiddle with the q values for **v**ideo and **a**udio if the result's not acceptable. Lower values are better but produce bigger files. For libtheora, it's the opposite - higher values are better. Range is 0-10.

Comment: Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: Theora & Vorbis](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide).

Comment: ... `-acodec libopus -b:a 128000` worked for me for opus, the quality level isn't supported apparently.